# AKS internal loadbalancer changing IP

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster configured with an `ingress-nginx` `internal` ingress controller of class nginx-internal. This creates an internal LB with a private IP. We then create a few ingress objects using the ingress class `nginx-internal`. These ingress objects gets assigned the ILBs private IP(external IP). So far so good.

Now, we upgraded `ingress-nginx` `internal` ingress controller(to version v1.2.0 from 0.49.0 as we had to upgrade to k8s v1.22.6) and this potentially caused the ILBs IP address to change. To our surprise, the ingress objects still have the old IPs assigned and not the new ones.

I would have thought the ingress controller would have figured this out and would have updated the IP addresses on the all ingress objects that it tracks.

Any help/explanations on what may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for `ingress-nginx` on the new version is to use Helm. This would ensure the new IPs would be used.

```bash
NAMESPACE=ingress-basic

helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --create-namespace \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

Check the Azure docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli